# "Уже", "как", "потому" — какие это части речи?

Tags: морфология, наречия

Уже карабкается (слово уже), как выбраться(слово как), потому продвигается(потому).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уже — наречие времени, как — вопросительное слово (наречие), потому — наречие.

Источник — «Малый академический словарь».